# Activity started but doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

Ok

I have manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ui.authorization.AuthActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.callsigns.SelectCallsignActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.order.waitorder.WaitOrderActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ui.balance.BalanceActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        />

    <activity   android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
                android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ui.order.gotorder.GoogleMapsActivity"/>

    <activity android:name=".ui.order.gotorder.OrderDetailsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

    <service android:name=".location.ServiceForLocation"/>


    <service android:name=".network.newsocket.NewSocketService"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="db0dc6f3ae8099a148926812fca7bd6cc29b4f4b"/>
</application>
```

...

Next start WaitOrderActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WaitOrderActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Next from callback but in WaitOrderActivity I start OrderDetailsActivity

After all I call again startActivity(WaitOrderActivity) or OrderDetailsActivity.this.finish, anyway I will be in WaitOrderActivity again. 
Trouble: in second time I see by logs what OrderDetailsActivity started, but I doesn't see that on the screen. I still see WaitOrderActivity. Why?

Comment: This is not clear at all, can you give us more structured details about all your activities, and what you do with them ?

Comment: Thank's for comment but i resolved my trouble. I set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK